# How to amend or add XML attribute with XSLT based on xml node sibligs value?

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there any way to amend XML by changing or adding an attribute based on nodes siblings/child value?

I need to transform:

```
<FieldMatchResult FieldName="Record_Amount">
```

into one of the following:

```
<FieldMatchResult FieldName="Record_1_Amount">
```

or

```
<FieldMatchResult FieldName="Record_Amount" Tag="Record_1_Amount">
```

here is my sample and I need to pull out value from "Row Index" element

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArtifactMatchResult xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
  <SubArtifacts>
    <ArtifactMatchResult ArtifactName="Data Record">
      <Fields>
        <FieldMatchResult FieldName="Record_Amount">
          <Values>
            <anyType xsi:type="xsd:double">123456.5</anyType>
          </Values>
        </FieldMatchResult>
        <FieldMatchResult FieldName="Record_Rate" >
          <Values>
            <anyType xsi:type="xsd:double">1.25</anyType>
          </Values>
        </FieldMatchResult>
        <FieldMatchResult FieldName="Row Index">
          <Values>
            <anyType xsi:type="xsd:double">1</anyType>
          </Values>
        </FieldMatchResult>
      </Fields>
      <SubArtifacts />
    </ArtifactMatchResult>
    <ArtifactMatchResult ArtifactName="Data Record">
      <Fields>
        <FieldMatchResult FieldName="Record_Amount">
          <Values>
            <anyType xsi:type="xsd:double">123456.5</anyType>
          </Values>
        </FieldMatchResult>
        <FieldMatchResult FieldName="Record_Rate" >
          <Values>
            <anyType xsi:type="xsd:double">1.25</anyType>
          </Values>
        </FieldMatchResult>
         <FieldMatchResult FieldName="Row Index">
          <Values>
            <anyType xsi:type="xsd:double">2</anyType>
          </Values>
        </FieldMatchResult>
     </Fields>
      <SubArtifacts />
    </ArtifactMatchResult>
  </SubArtifacts>
</ArtifactMatchResult>
```

Many thanks for any pointers.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*based on nodes siblings/child value*"? Please provide clear criteria: if this, then that, otherwise something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following-sibling [axis](http://xmlplease.com/axis) with the following template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="XML" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="ArtifactMatchResult/SubArtifacts/ArtifactMatchResult/Fields">
    <FieldMatchResult FieldName="Record_Amount">
      <xsl:attribute name="Tag">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('Record_', */following-sibling::FieldMatchResult[@FieldName = 'Row Index']/Values/anyType, '_Amount')" />
      </xsl:attribute>
    </FieldMatchResult>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

- `concat()` concatenates two or more strings separated by a comma.
- `*` selects all the children of the context node.
- `following-sibling::FieldMatchResult` selects all the `FieldMatchResult` siblings nodes that follow the children of the context node.
- `[@FieldName = 'Row Index']` selects all nodes that have a FieldName attribute of value 'Row Index'.

This XSLT, applied to your XML, gives the following result:

```
  <FieldMatchResult FieldName="Record_Amount" Tag="Record_1_Amount"/>
  <FieldMatchResult FieldName="Record_Amount" Tag="Record_2_Amount"/>
```

Comment: I will give it a go later this week
thanks for description